# Can instances exist inside a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I would like to know if instances exist inside a class. I've made a bicycle system which produces different types of bicycles. I would like to know if objects of different types of cycles can exist inside a class also I got its code for which I want someone to review it and tell me if it's good or bad. The file link is attached, it would be great if someone reviewed it and told me about any mistakes or improvements [Code link](https://mega.nz/#!J1FUHSDR!tUCpAlYzHbUaCiRSGo1jS9TB3cqOVm0VJJXEerXHhBI)

Comment: Have you tried any of this? What difficulties did you encounter exactly? "i got it's code for which I want someone to review it and tell me if it's good or bad,the file link is attached,must review it and tell me about any mistakes or improvements" That is not what StackOverflow is for. It is for *specific programming questions*

Comment: Perhaps try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for your code review question.

Comment: please provide a code sample not a downloadable, for your case you should check the singleton partern : https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Singleton.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's understand what classes and objects are first. A class is analogous with a set, while the object is an instance of that set. Let's suppose you have a class called Citizen. This would be a general concept of citizen of a state. If you instantiate Citizen, you will get an object as a result, who is a particular Citizen. Nowm a Citizen object has some attributes, like name, age and some abilities, like vote. These attributes and abilities are basically the attributes and abilities of the individual.

A class may have attributes and abilities on its own. For instance, the Citizen class might have the ability to celebrate a national holiday and yes, it can have attributes, like president. Is the president a Citizen? Yes, he/she is. A very special citizen, who is worthy to be available from the general concept of Citizen.

There is no technical problem in defining a member of the class to be an instance of the same class. That's a perfectly valid thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes , Why not ?**

Everything in Python are objects , so if you have a simple list inside your class ,that's another object inside your class!

You can even have your own custom class objects inside your class

Comment: The question was whether it is allowed to have instances of a class to be members of the class.